# bootstrap navbar-toggler button click change the list item color and size to default for one second?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
.navbar .collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
 font-family: 'yekan';
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .8;
  font-size: .9rem;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                                </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">sthing1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">sthing2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">sthing3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">sthing4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <div>
        <button id="btn-search" class="my-2 my-sm-0 fa-pull-left " type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        <input class="search-input form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="search" aria-label="Search">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

When i click the navbar-toggler class to show the list,for one second when its opening the color and size of list convert to black . why is it happening? how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your CSS you already set color white (#fff) for nav-link. Bootstrap default add **.show** class into  Using JS. So, bootstrap pre-defined color simply override with your CSS. You can define another color when **.show** class added via default bootstap JS event. Check the following [LiveFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/khzst9en/13/) OR Code Snippet below

```css
.navbar .collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
 font-family: 'yekan';
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .8;
  font-size: .9rem;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px
}
.navbar .collapse.show .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                                </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">sthing1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">sthing2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">sthing3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">sthing4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <div>
        <button id="btn-search" class="my-2 my-sm-0 fa-pull-left " type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        <input class="search-input form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="search" aria-label="Search">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```